# What is the best way to create a copy of an entire S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to create a copy of an entire S3 bucket.

The bucket currently contains around 4TB of data and mostly comprises small files of size around 200KB, we have around 20000000 files.

I came across two ways through which we can achieve this S3 Object Copy Batch job, Replication.

But I am not sure how much time it will take to complete and the cost involved.

I am just trying to identify what is the best way to copy the complete bucket (along with the time taken and cost involved)

Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: **Side-question:** Why do you have 20 million objects? How is this data being used? There is probably a better way to store this data that will make it easier to keep, compress and query.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein We have 20 million XML files. We have 20 million files because of the data resulting from transactions over many years. For around a year these files will be retrieved several times and also overwritten them few times.  Every file is independent and cannot be related to other files. In this case, If there is a better way to store data, please suggest it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The best way to copy this would be to use [Amazon S3 batch operations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/batch-ops.html), using the [Copy objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/batch-ops-copy-object.html) option:

- First, use [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html) to create a list of all objects in the bucket (this normally operates as a daily operation, so it might require 24 hours to be available)
- Then, use an Amazon S3 Batch Operation to copy the objects to another bucket, using the S3 Inventory report as an input

I'm not sure how long the Copy operation would take. I assume the cost for copying the 20 million objects would involve *at least*:

- 20 million GET requests (20,000,000 / 1,000 * $0.0004) = $8
- 20 million PUT requests (20,000,000 / 1,000 * $0.005) = $100
- The additional 4TB of storage would cost $92/month

This assumes that both buckets are in the same Region, so Data Transfer will not apply.

As an aside, I would highly recommend that you re-think why you would need 20 million objects. It might be more efficient to combine the objects together, which would make them easier to access and query.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and information. We are new to using S3. I found from the pricing page that We are charged for S3 Batch Operations jobs, objects, and requests in addition to any charges associated with the operation that S3 Batch Operations performs on our behalf, including data transfer, requests, and other charges. Ths is $0.25 per job and $1.00 per million object operations performed. I am clear with the pricing details.

Comment: I know that you replied that you were unsure how long the Copy operation would take.
But for any other scenarios/examples, it will be very helpful if you could help me with the time taken by the Copy operation to complete

Comment: I find the idea of combining objects together interesting. Since we are new to S3, could you please suggest how can we combine objects together, we would need to retrieve the object several times, and also we would have to overwrite the files few times during a year. Every object here is an XML file that is needed by another system on demand. The lifespan of an object currently is 1 year after which they will be archived.

Comment: If you only access each file a few times and you always know which file to access, then using S3 in this way is probably quite effective. Putting the information in a database would make search and retrieval easier, but would be more costly. Amazon S3 is not efficient at "listing" millions of objects, but if you always know which one you need without listing/searching, then your current method seems fine.